# linked list pointer assignment why cant we directly assign tail to temp instead of tail->tail next

Tags: c++, linked-list

```
void add_node(int n) {

    node *tmp = new node;    
    tmp->data = n;           
    tmp->next = NULL;

    if(head == NULL) {
        head = tmp;
        tail = tmp;
    }
    else {
        tail->next = tmp;
        tail = tail->next;
    }
}
```

in the else statement, why cant i directly assign tail=tmp; instead of tail=tail->next; is there anything Im missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you enter the function, where does `tail->next` point?

Comment: tail is assigned to null.. so i guess tail->next is also null then? idk if im right

Comment: Also, try to draw out a linked list on paper, using small boxes for the nodes. Try to do all the manipulations on paper. It could help seeing it like that.

Comment: If the list is not empty, which means it will go into the `else` part, then `tail` should *not* be a null pointer. But `tail->next` *should* be. So what happens then if you do `tail = tail->next;`? Shouldn't `tail` always point to the last node in the list? And how would the new node `tmp` be linked into the list?

Comment: so are you sayin that tail=tmp shouldnt be done but youre not able to explain over here on keyboard?

Comment: As long as you have `tail->next = tmp;` first, the two assignments should be equivalent.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp sure right bro?

Comment: Yes, see this [mcve]: https://ideone.com/DnN55z

Comment: Re-reading your question and your comments, I think most of us misunderstood your question. Doing `tail = tail->next` or `tail = tmp` is the same, *after* linking the node into the list.

Comment: You *could* do that, but the code as written makes  the intent (move the tail pointer to the new tail) clearer. I would personally need to at least double-check the change you’re suggesting.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: Your question basically comes down to this: "Instead of saying `a = b`, can I say `a = c` since `b == c`?" The answer should be obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a small simple list:

```
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+
| node1 | --> | node2 | --> | node3 |
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+
^                           ^
|                           |
head                        tail
```

Now to add a new node at the end of the list, we first add the new node to the list, by making the tails `next` pointer point to the new node:

```
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
| node1 | --> | node2 | --> | node3 | --> | node4 |
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
^                           ^
|                           |
head                        tail
```

This is what the assignment `tail->next = tmp` does.

Then we update `tail` to point to the new tail:

```
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
| node1 | --> | node2 | --> | node3 | --> | node4 |
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+     +-------+
^                                         ^
|                                         |
head                                      tail
```

This is what the assignment `tail = tail->next` does. Of course, this could also be done by doing `tail = tmp`.

The order of the two assignments is important.

---

Now if you do it the opposite way, by assigning `tail = tail->next` first, when we have

```
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+
| node1 | --> | node2 | --> | node3 |
+-------+     +-------+     +-------+
^
|
head
```

You no longer have a tail! You don't know where the list ends, and where to insert the new node unless you loop over the whole list to find a node whose `next` pointer is a null pointer.

Comment: The step where "Then we update tail to point to the new tail:"
So how do you do it? 

tail=temp
or 
tail=tail->next

Comment: Thanks a ton bro!

Answer (score 0):

You *can* do that, but it will not produce the correct result.  Trace it with a debugger if you can't figure out why from looking at the code.

Comment: I'm quite a beginner here.. couldn't really find out what kinda difference it would make

Comment: Sounds like you need a better debugger.